# Way to auto-populate database without using loads of "insert into" statements? MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a mock database for a mobile phone company with thousands of records. So far in my short studies of mySQL I know that a statement like this will create a table and insert a record in the table.

```
    create table MOCK_DATA1 (
    id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    country VARCHAR(50),
    ip_address VARCHAR(20)
);
insert into MOCK_DATA1 (id, first_name, last_name, email, country, ip_address) values (1, 'Benjamin', 'Wagner', 'bwagner0@linkedin.com', 'China', '42.197.209.108');
```

Instead of writing thousands of "insert into" statements, is there a way that I can make this loop with relatively unique data each time?

Alternatively, I have generated (using a free website) an SQL file with around about 1000 of insert into statements for this table, I know I could simply use these but if there was a neater, easier way than writing 1000 insert into statements and simply "loading" this data in without 1000 insert intos, google hasn't helped me so far.

Comment: You can do it with one statement. Check the syntax of `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the synthetic data using a script in a language of your choice or even Excel. Save this data as a CSV file. Use `load infile` or `mysqlimport` to load this data into your database.

Answer (score 0):

please explain how much related data you want to insert and how ?

do you have any  form of it ready with you like .xls file or  .csv file or any file  because if that is case we can do it in couple of minutes but if not .

Plan b : create  single insert query  and  copy paiste it 1000 or more times without primary key in any text file  and  save as  .sql file and import into your table  it will give your all record with diffrent  ids.

hope any one is useful for you .

Comment: I have a .sql file with 1000 insert intos here. All I want is for there to be 1000 records within this table without having to use 1000 insert into statements. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg001722j2gzmxu/MOCK_DATA1.sql?dl=0

Comment: and you don't want to use import  it from gui too ??